# How can I add a paragraph break in a logon message?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I'm trying to use the group policy setting "Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on" but I'm having trouble getting the formatting of the message right; my paragraph breaks (i.e., blank lines) disappear as soon as I press Apply.

I found a suggestion to use ALT-255 ([non-breaking space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) as an invisible character, which seemed to work at first, but resulted in the message being truncated when displayed on the clients.

I like my blank lines.  How can I get them to stay put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows Server 2016, the following sequence of characters, if placed at the beginning of a paragraph, will display (on Windows 10 clients) as a blank line: quotation mark, space, comma, quotation mark.

In the Security Policy Setting dialog, it looks like this:

```
First paragraph.
" ,"Second paragraph.
```

In the Group Policy Management editor, it looks like this:

```
First paragraph.," ,"Second paragraph.
```

In the Group Policy Management console, it looks like this:

```
First paragraph., " ,"Second paragraph.
```

Unfortunately, every time you edit the group policy object, you will need to recreate the paragraph breaks.  My recommendation is to use a separate group policy object just for the logon message, so that you will not break the logon message inadvertently while making an unrelated change.

---

Another alternative is to directly edit the `GptTmpl.inf` for the relevant GPO, using any text editor you wish, from the Sysvol share on any Domain Controller.  The path looks like this:

```
\\mycompany.com\Sysvol\mycompany.com\Policies\{GUID}\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit
```

Where `{GUID}` is replaced with the GUID of the GPO, shown in the Details tab of the Group Policy Management Console.

In this case, an end of line is represented by a comma, a blank line looks like this:

```
First paragraph.," ",Second paragraph.
```

and embedded commas must be put in quotes.

---

For completeness, you can also [use a startup script to set the logon message](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/02/08/deploying-legal-notices-to-domain-computers-using-group-policy/) although this seems ridiculously rigmarolish to me when there's a perfectly good group policy setting to do it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues trying to add 2 breaks so I would have 2 paragraphs with 1 blank line between.  Here is the format that worked for me:

First paragraph text." ," " ,"Second paragraph text.

Came out looking like this:

First paragraph text.

Second paragraph text.